# How to get past the consent page of google shopping using requests and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

For a small project I tried to get past the google consent page to webscrape the prices found by it. However i could not get the to the good stuff. Sofar i tried the following code, as also proposed by [Using python requests with google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66957948/using-python-requests-with-google-search).

First try:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
#%% get acces

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
"cookie": "CONSENT=YES"}

cookie = {
    'set-cookie': 'CONSENT=YES+cb.20211212-16-p1.nl+FX+671'
}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=kitesurf+bar&rlz=1C1CAFA_enNL603NL674&sxsrf=AOaemvJF3BPrjeczkCI1e1YotCSJYcKjug:1641909060258&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBwqjy66n1AhXO-KQKHUKVBSoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url,headers=headers)
purl = 'https://consent.google.com/s'
payload = {
'gl': 'NL',
'm': 'false',
'pc': 'srp',
'continue': 'https://www.google.com/search?q=kitesurf+bar&rlz=1C1CAFA_enNL603NL674&sxsrf=AOaemvJF3BPrjeczkCI1e1YotCSJYcKjug:1641909060258&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBwqjy66n1AhXO-KQKHUKVBSoQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw',
'ca': 'r',
'x': '6',
'v': 'cb.20211212-16-p1.nl+FX+092',
't': 'ADw3F8jHa3HqOqq133-wOkXCYf4K_r-AIA:1641909071268',
'hl': 'nl',
'src': '1'
}
s.post(purl,params=payload,headers=headers)
page = s.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookie)
```

Second try:

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    # url = f"https://www.google.com/search?q=fitness+wear"
    headers = {
        "referer":"referer: https://www.google.com/",
        "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
        }
    s.post(url, headers=headers)
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)```
````

Comment: What problem are you facing on the second try?

Comment: @arsho, still no information regarding the name and price etc of the items displayed